# How would I force qt to use a certain version of mingw?

Tags: qt, mingw, mingw-w64

I am new to Qt and mingw and would like to know how to configure the qt SDK (I am using the one off of the nokia site version 1.2.1) to use a specific version of mingw (4.6.3 64 bit to be exact).

Would I need to replace certain mingw files in the qtSDK installation? Or is there a configuration menu in Qt creator to set it up a certain way?

Would I have to install mingw separately and link the two somehow? I am entirely clueless on this matter so please leave nothing to assumption.

Comment: In the `Projects` tab of QtCreator you can override the build steps and use any executable file (in your case any version of mingw you have) there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have to install a separate MinGW tool-chains if you don't want to use the one shipped with the SDK.

2) For multiple compilers, add your additional compilers from menu: Tools -> Options -> Build & Run -> 'Kits ' / 'Compilers'.

Ref: [Adding Tool Chains](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-tool-chains.html)